# Derivation of the kinematics equation $\Delta x=v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, physics, kinematics

$\vec{s}$ is an arbitrary position vector, which can change with time.

$\vec{v} = \dfrac{\Delta \vec{s}}{\Delta t}$ is the velocity vector.

$\vec{a} = \dfrac{\Delta \vec{v}}{\Delta t}$ is the acceleration vector, and it readily follows that
\begin{align*}
\vec{v_f} & =\vec{v_i}+\vec{a}\Delta t\\
\dfrac{\Delta \vec{s}}{\Delta t} & =\vec{v_i}+\vec{a}\Delta t\\
\Delta \vec{s} & =\vec{v_i}\Delta t+\vec{a}(\Delta t)^2
\end{align*}

However, this differs from the accepted $\Delta x=v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$.

What is wrong with my reasoning, and how can I get to the correct answer using purely vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Your second to last step is the statement
$$\frac{\Delta{\bf s}}{\Delta t}={\bf v}_f$$
which doesn't make a lot of sense. One could argue that it makes more sense to use the velocity at the middle of the time interval $\Delta t$, in which case you get the desired result.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't make sense, though, because I'm simply substituting in definitions. Is there any sort of mathematical principle that makes it clear why I would need to use the velocity in the middle of the interval?

Comment: The velocity is changing in that time interval. There is no obvious reason to use the middle of the interval, but it undoubtedly makes more sense than the velocity at the beginning or end of the interval. To make a long story short, you should do this with calculus instead.

Answer (score 1):

### What is wrong with the OP's approach?

Please first note that the desired equation is derived for motion of an object with constant acceleration (vector).

All the OP's steps are right *except* the **penultimate** one in which the OP used the definition of average velocity for (instant) velocity. In fact, we have$$\mathbf{v}_{\text{avg}} = \frac{\Delta \mathbf{s}}{\Delta t},$$where $\Delta \mathbf{s}$ denotes the displacement vector of the object during the time interval $\Delta t = t_2 - t_1$ (bold letters represent vectors).

To derive the desired equation, we need to ***define*** (instant) velocity of the object. This can be done in the following ways. In each approach the desired equation will be obtained according to the associated definition.

### Calculus-based Approach

This is the correct and rigorous way of defining velocity:$$\mathbf{v} = \frac{d \mathbf{s}}{dt}= \lim _{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta \mathbf{s}}{\Delta t}.$$

Using this definition and regarding that the acceleration is constant, we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{a}_{\text{avg}} = \frac{\Delta \mathbf{v}}{\Delta t}\\
\Rightarrow \quad & \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}_0 + \mathbf{a} \Delta t\\
\Rightarrow \quad & \int _{t_0}^t \frac{d\mathbf{s}}{dt} \, dt = \int _{t_0}^t \mathbf{v}_0 \, dt + \int _{t_0}^t \mathbf{a}t \, dt\\
\Rightarrow \quad & \Delta \mathbf{s} = \mathbf{v}_0 \Delta t + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{a} (\Delta t)^2
\end{align*}

### Precalculus-based Approach

As the reader may not familiar with calculus ideas, let us define velocity non-rigorously for the case of motion of an object with constant acceleration.

To avoid dealing with infinitesimals, entities arisen in calculus, let us assume that for some small enough finite time interval $\Delta \tau$ motion of an object is constant so that we can define velocity of an object at any instant within the time interval $\Delta \tau$ to be the average velocity of the object over $\Delta \tau$. From finitistic mathematics and observable physics points of view, this assumption sounds plausible enough to substitute for the classical calculus idea.

Now, consider motion of an object with constant acceleration, which means that the velocity will be linear with respect to time. Suppose that the velocity of the object has changed from $\mathbf{v}_0$ to $\mathbf{v}$ during the time interval $\Delta t$, with displacement $\Delta \mathbf{s}$ and average velocity $\mathbf{v}_{\text{avg}}$. Let us partition $\Delta t$ into $n$ equal, small enough (with respect to our assumption) time intervals $\Delta \tau$, with associated displacements $\Delta \mathbf{s}_i$ and velocities $\mathbf{v}_i$. So we have
\begin{align*}
\Delta \mathbf{s} & = \Delta \mathbf{s}_0 + \dots + \Delta \mathbf{s}_{n-1}\\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{\Delta \mathbf{s}}{\Delta t} & = \frac{\Delta \mathbf{s}_0}{n\Delta \tau} + \dots + \frac{\Delta \mathbf{s}_{n-1}}{n\Delta \tau}\\
\Rightarrow \quad \mathbf{v}_{\text{avg}} & = \frac{\mathbf{v}_0 + \dots + \mathbf{v}_{n-1}}{n}\\
\Rightarrow \quad \mathbf{v}_{\text{avg}} & = \frac{\mathbf{v}_0 + \mathbf{v}}{2}
\end{align*}
(for getting the last step we used the fact that the velocities $\mathbf{v}_i$ are in arithmetic progression since in constant-acceleration motion velocity is linearly proportional to time, noting that the average of terms in arithmetic progression equals the average of the first and the last terms).

Now, to obtain the desired equation, we proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\Delta \mathbf{s} & = \mathbf{v}_{\text{avg}} \Delta t\\
& = \left ( \frac{\mathbf{v}_0 + \mathbf{v}}{2} \right ) \Delta t\\
& = \left ( \frac{\mathbf{v}_0 + \mathbf{v}_0 + \mathbf{a} \Delta t}{2} \right ) \Delta t\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{a} (\Delta t)^2 + \mathbf{v}_0 \Delta t
\end{align*}